# Java-8 stream get all

Tags: java-8

I have a List of objects and I will simple get a property of all the objects in a list.
I know its simple but acutally I havn't found how I can do it:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = ...

MyOblect myObject = new ...
myObject.myProperty = ...
```

My approach:

```
myObjects.stream().findAll(s -> s.getMyProperty())...
```

Comment: What do you mean with “get a property of all the objects”? If your list has *n* objects, you have *n* values for that property. Besides that, your problem might stem from your stretching of the word “find”. Maybe you want to *collect* values instead…

Comment: myObjects.stream().map(s -> s.getMyProperty()).collect(Collectors.toList()) - you will get list of myProperty of all objects

Answer (score 3):

You are probably searching for `map` and `collect` methods:

```
List<T> list = myObjects.stream().map(s -> s.getMyProperty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: List<?> as a return type will make the code compiles

Comment: Also, you could "simplify" this like this: 
myObjects.stream().map(MyObject::getMyProperty).collect(Collectors.toList());